# How to check if an NSMutableDictionary contains Value (not Key) in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to check if `NSMutableDictionary` contains Value (not contains key) or not in iOS.

Comment: If you're using a dictionary and only want to retrieve values, I suggest you consider maybe using an NSSet(or NSMutabeSet), or even an NS(Mutable)Array.
If it's not an option in your case then some answers below are just fine :)

Answer (score 3):

```
NSMutableDictionary *testDictionary; // a mutable dictionary in which you want to find a particular value
NSArray *values = [testDictionary allValues]; // get all values from the dictionary
[values containsObject:@"valueToBeFound"];//search for the value that you want to search
```

Comment: Even though your answer works and is fine, you lose the speed of the dictionary by transforming it to the "slow" array. But still, if we're talking about a small number of items then the answer is as valid as any.

Comment: The only way to check if your value is in a dictionary is by checking all values in a dictionary... if you want quicker access you'll need a different data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a category on NSDictionary you might want to use:

Put in **NSDictionary-ContainsValue.h**

```
@interface NSDictionary (ContainsValue)

-(BOOL)containsValue:(id)value;

@end;
```

Put in **NSDictionary-ContainsValue.m**

```
@implementation NSDictionary (ContainsValue)

-(BOOL)containsValue:(id)value {
    __block BOOL found = NO;
    [self enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull key, id  _Nonnull obj, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        if ([value isEqual:obj]) {
            found = YES;
            *stop = YES;
        }
    }];
    return found;
}

@end
```

Then import the header in your implementation:

```
#import "NSDictionary-ContainsValue.h"
```

Call the method:

```
BOOL found = [yourDictionary containsValue:someValue];
```

You may want to change the `isEqual` test with `==` - your question wasn't specific in that regard. Using `isEqual:` matches the behavior of `containsValue:` of `NSArray`, though. Often, this is what you want.

Comment: Did you measure? 1000 checks are pretty fast. Of course, if you're doing things over and over, it may not be fast enough. But then we need more context for a better solution - and maybe using a dictionary alone won't be the best option, then.

Comment: You will need those checks anyway. You cannot tell something is there or not without looking at the elements. This method should be the fastest way to do it - it doesn't create unnecessary arrays and stops right away when finding it.

Comment: this method work only NSArray and NSMutableArray. not work in NSMutableDictionary.

Comment: No, this code is a category on NSDictionary. Do you know what a category is? Copy the complete code, not just the method.

Comment: plz, give simple example !!

Comment: There is no example to give - it's all there. Just include that code (in .h and .m files), and call BOOL found = [yourDictionary containsValue:someValue];

Comment: @bhadresh I added some more remarks and changed the implementation to match that of NSArray (using isEqual: for comparison).

Comment: Hi Eiko, I don't get how this code works. Since enumerateKeysAndObjects is using a block, I thought the method would always hit the `return NO` statement... Could you explain how it works?

Comment: @bhadresh, you shouldn't be begging for code. You should take this answer, and use it as an opportunity to _learn_. Once you copy it, it becomes _your_ code, _your_ responsibility.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. It's looking for the case where a given key and its value (`obj`) are equal to each other. That is not at all what the OP wants. Perhaps you should see if `value` is equal to `obj`.

Comment: @maddy Thank you for pointing this out. Happens when you don't have a test for it but just make sure it compiles. Fixed.

Answer (score -2):

The easy Way if you find only value , if key does not matter then use **NSPredicate**,

**Example:-**

Your Dictionary

```
 NSMutableDictionary *eventData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
       [eventData setObject:@"Jun 13, 2012 12:00:00 AM" forKey:@"eventDate"];
     [eventData setObject:@"hjhj" forKey:@"text"];
```

Use predicate to search only Value,

```
 NSArray *resultArray = [[eventData allValues] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF like %@", @"hjhj"]];
```

It will give you all matching value in array.

Comment: That's too bad. Rather inefficient, and very limited in the number of value types you can use this on, basically it's string compare.

Comment: @Eiko he have 1000 record. so predicate is better way rather than use key and value .

Comment: @bhadresh can you post your dictionary ? I have tested it and then post here.

Comment: @BadalShah The predicate is clearly inferior in any way here. It's slow, but most of all, it won't work with anything but strings or things that have a description (debug!) method that's good enough.

Comment: @Eiko well its depend on situation. If , Multiple key with different name contain same value and if, i want to find only value then which one is the best option ?

Comment: @BadalShah Please understand that your answer won't work for most types of data put into a NSDictionary. And even if it does, it is horribly slow because it converts all objects to strings in order to compare them. If it works in this case, be happy because it is just slow this time. Often, it won't work at all.

Comment: @Eiko . yes . you are right sir. Thanks for sharing knowledge.  I understand all scenario with "it converts all objects to strings in order to compare them" this line. It will become slow. Sorry but i want to know one more thing , which one is best way if multiple key contain same value ? just for my knowledge.

Comment: @BadalShah Iteration / Enumaration will work in all cases. There's no difference how often the value is contained in the dictionary. Even the "predicate way" will go through all the data, just packed up in a more expensive way.